Transactions bundled with jito appearing with the same maker on dexscreener
Anyone using jito bundles in here?
I had some transactions (buys) from a snipe bot that were bundled, and every transaction made with different a wallet. Do you know why the transactions appear with the maker is the same on Dexscreener? Or how can I do the bundling so that it appears the wallet address or some different address? On birdeye it shows the different wallet addresses
birdeye: https://imgur.com/8hApQf3
descreener: https://imgur.com/8O0rQEX
